# How to put image from drawable folder at HTML file

Tags: android

I have a HTML file in my /res/raw/test.html

and i show it in web view using following code

```
WebView wbview = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
InputStream fin;
    try
    {
        fin = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.manual);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[fin.available()];
        fin.read(buffer);
        fin.close();
        wbview.loadData(new String(buffer), "text/html", "UTF-8");
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

And this is my code of my HTML file

```
<html>
    <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
    </p>
  <table>
   <tr>
         <td>
       <img src=\\"file:///android_asset/test_image2.jpg\"/>    
           <img src="test_image2.jpg" width="50px" alt="Hi">

       <img src=\"res/drawable/test_image.png"/>
       <img src="file:///android_res/drawable/test_image.png" />
       <img src=\"file:///android_res/drawable/test_image.png"\ />
         </td>
   </tr>
</table>
</html>
```

I want to display the image from my resource folder in my html file...
i tried all possibility still not work. It's just show a HTML text but for a image i don't have idea how to show it

Please help me

Comment: you can check this answer by 
Jonas Alves


 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4534043/android-add-image-to-webview-from-a-drawable

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can load your html page from android assets folder like below code.

```
WebView webView = new WebView(this);
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/manual.html");
setContentView(webView);
```

and also you need to make your html like this below .

```
 <html>
  <p>
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
  </p>
<table>
  <tr>
      <td>
     <img src="file:///android_asset/test_image2.jpg"/>    
      <img src="file:///android_asset/test_image2.jpg" width="50px" alt="Hi">
     <img src="file:///android_res/drawable/test_image.png"/>
     <img src="file:///android_res/drawable/test_image.png" />
     <img src="file:///android_res/drawable/test_image.png" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </html>
```

Comment: +1 exact solution. Suggestion: Place the images inside the asset folder and no need to write file:///android_asset path, just reference it by RelativePath using . (dot)

Comment: Yes it's work very well..
Actually i need my HTML files still in res folder so a localization will work i modified your solution to 

    ...
    wbview.loadUrl("file:///android_res/raw/manual.html");
    ...

and put res/raw/manual.html and res/raw-jp/manual.html, etc 


maybe my problem before at this code

    wbview.loadData(new String(buffer), "text/html", "UTF-8");

this line make html just showing text only


Thanks for an answers

Comment: if i put image into assets it works fine, but not in drawable

Comment: @Herry: This works well for images in your own app. But do you know how we refer to bundled images, like `@android:drawable/ic_menu_info_details.png`?

Comment: Remember to add a rule to proguard config file to let it work also on production apk: -keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
    public static <fields>;
}

-keep class **.R$*
see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6280188/prevent-proguard-to-remove-specific-drawables?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Comment: @Herry it is not working in my case "<img src="file:///android_res/drawable/test_image.png"/>"

Comment: <img src="file:///android_res/drawable/test_image.png"/> 
this was not working

Comment: @LuisA.Florit Did you get the solution?